# Do dimmer switches work properly with any kind of lamp?

Tags: light, dimming

I have a dimmer switch installed in my room that I like very much, but lately incandescent lamps became harder to find, and soon (in a few years or so, if I'm not mistaken) they will be gone to be succeeded by other kinds of lamps.

My question is will LED and fluorescent lamps work with dimmer switches properly?

Comment: Your question is a bit open-ended, to the extent that it indicates lack of research prior to posting. Adding a list of specific lamp types you are considering, and specific dimmers you want to use, might enhance its value. Dimmers do exist for LED lights - but the one your room might not be it.

Comment: I don't know much about dimmers, I just know the one I have works perfectly with incandescent lamps.

Comment: Also make sure you distinguish between *leading-edge dimmers* and *trailing-edge dimmers*. The old dimmers are leading-edge and they may not work with new dimmable LEDs or CFLs that require a trailing-edge dimmer.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, you need special CFL or LED bulbs to work with dimmers. Some will work with standard incandescent dimmers, some need specific CFL or LED dimmers.

The reason for this is that a standard incandescent bulb works off direct (AC) voltage. A lamp or lighting fixture is directly connected to the wiring in your home, and that's it. Nothing but metal and the filament in the bulb. A dimmer basically cuts the voltage in half (or a certain percentage depending on how much you are dimming) by resistance or by a solid state relay cutting the voltage on/off as needed (PWM, averaging the on/off periods), but the bulb still works by the filament heating up as normal, just less brightly. Filament incandescent bulbs are DUMB.

LED and CFLs on the other hand, have control electronics in them. They are SMART. Not just resistors, but rectifying the AC voltage, stepping it up/down, current control, ballast, etc. The ones that arn't designed for dimmers have a very very small input range (110~120 AC ± a few volts) that the electronics inside are designed for. Fall out of that range, and it won't work, and can cause damage. New and specialty ones take customer needs in mind, and fix or improve or add features that make the electronics work with a dimmer, with either resisted or pwmed dimmers.

Not all LED/CFL bulbs will work with your specific dimmer, but there is a good chance that ones marketed as Dimmable, will work.

Comment: Neither resistance nor solid state relays are commonly used; resistance would be way too lossy (hot), solid state relays are expensive - triacs or thyristors are generally used (leading edge dimmers), transistors in more upmarket designs (trailing edge dimmers)

Comment: Also note that while only those CFL and LED bulbs marketed as dimmable are, um, dimmable, success can also hinge on the dimmer itself.  I went through four dimmable CFLs from one brand before I called customer service and was told that my dimmer was "unsupported" by their dimmable CFL.  I never dug into the details (also never bought that brand bulb again), but I assume that the dimmer had some un-snubbed switching transients that this particular cost-minimized dimming CFL couldn't handle.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Probably no
Long answer: It depends on the type of lamps. there are various dimmers available for inductive, capacitive and resistive lamps (usually they support inductive/resistive lamps or capacitive/resistive lamps).

Just an example: For low voltage halogen bulbs (12V) it depends on the type of transformer you use. E.g. you can use a electronic transformer (those small bars), they have a capacitive characteristic - you would need a dimmer which can handle that. Or you can have the same bulb with a normal transformer (those bulky heavy things) which has an inductive characteristic - you would need a dimmer which can handle that.

The old incandescent lights were pretty easy to dim because they have a mainly resistive characteristic which is supported by about every dimmer.

Alright - now forgive me for maybe using strange words, but writing such technical terms in a different language is difficult for me :)